# How to save two variables in an array as key and value [PHP]

Tags: php

I'm currently writing a script that searches for .md files and extracts a string out of it but I'm running into problems concerning saving this string in an array.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$flags = \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS;
$iterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($userContent, $flags);
$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $v) {

    $checkFiles = strpos($v, ".md");
    $url = array();

    if (!$checkFiles == '') {

        $mdFile = $v;
        $mdContent = file_get_contents($mdFile);
        $mdBreak = strpos($mdContent, "url: ");
        $mdContent = substr($mdContent, $mdBreak + 5);
        $mdBreak = strpos($mdContent, "\n");
        $mdUrl = substr($mdContent, 0, $mdBreak);

        echo $mdUrl . ' => ' . $mdFile;
        echo '<br>';

        $url[$mdUrl] = $mdFile;

    }

}
```

The script succeeds in finding the .md files and also succeeds in finding the `url: custom-url` inside those documents.

Furthermore `echo $mdUrl . ' => ' . $mdFile;` returns `custom-url => /content/default.md` but apparently saving the url as key and the path as value does not work as `print_r($url)` returns `Array ( [url-test ] => SplFileInfo Object ( [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /content/default.md [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => default.md ) )`

Could someone tell me what I did wrong and maybe help with fixing the script?

---

EDIT: Apparently it was a problem of the variable I tried to set as value.

As soon as I replaced `$mdFile = $v` with `$mdFile = (string)$v;` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the `$mdUrl` array again and again on each loop. I guess you wanted to initialize it above the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks, did not see that, but even if I initialize the array right after the iterator-variable and before the foreach-loop, it still does not work.